# How to increment a value in an API url

Tags: api, limit, offset

I have an API with an offset value and limit value
String requestUrl = https://url//offset=0&offset=1000;
this will fetch first 1000 details.
I need some more details and for that I need to send the API multiple times.
say for example I need execute this API 5 times and offset value should change for the first time to be 1001 and limit to be 2001
How can we implement this in a generic method in java.

Answer (score 1):

I dont undertand where is your problem, you just have to do that :

```
x = 1000;
x += 1000;
url = "https://url?offsetStart=" + (x - 1000) + "&offsetEnd=" + x;
```

And for an API, you can have 2 same parameter like "offset", try "offsetStart" and "offsetEnd"